# Waves on a slack string

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, string

hello im doing an experiment on waves and i need to know how to calculate the wavespeed of a wave in a circular slack string hanging from a pulley. Is there an equation for this? Is there tension in the string if its just hanging freely? How can the waves travel if there is no tension?
I am also unsure as to how to draw the diagram and where the forces are acting.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: The tension at a point on the string is given by the weight below that point. This looks like a Lariat chain (a science exhibit), there are videos on Youtube.